# selecting from orientDB in rhino

Tags: javascript, rhino, orientdb

I'm trying to access an orientDB from a [rhino script](https://github.com/wholcomb/tip/blob/master/test/orientDB/rhino). I'm getting the error

```
js: Can't find method com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseRecordWrapperAbstract.query(com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.OSQLSynchQuery)
```

when I execute the following code:

```
var System = java.lang.System
var OSQLSynchQuery = Packages.com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.OSQLSynchQuery
var ODatabaseDocumentTx = Packages.com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx
var ODocument = Packages.com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument
var File = java.io.File

var user_home = System.getProperty( "user.home" )
var db_path = user_home + "/.testdb"
var db_url = "local:" + db_path + File.separator + "db"
if( ! new File( db_path ).exists() ) {
    new File( db_path ).mkdirs()
    new ODatabaseDocumentTx( db_url ).create()
}
var db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx( db_url ).open( "admin", "admin" )
db.getStorage().getConfiguration().txSegment.setSynchRecord( true )

print( 'Select From TestObj' )

if( db.getMetadata().getSchema().getClass( 'TestObj' ) != null  ) {
    var result = db.query( new OSQLSynchQuery( "select * from TestObj" ) )
    print( "# of Entries: " + result.size() )
}
db.close()
```

I'm accessing an already created and populated database. The select works from the console.

I've checked the javadoc and ODatabaseRecordWrapperAbstract.query method takes an OQuery which OSQLSynchQuery implements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [query method](http://www.orientdb.org/releases/latest/javadoc/com/orientechnologies/orient/core/db/ODatabaseComplex.html#query%28com.orientechnologies.orient.core.query.OQuery,%20java.lang.Object...%29) is using varargs. Rhino probably cannot handle that. Try to pass in an extra empty Object array:

```
 var result = db.query(
     new OSQLSynchQuery( "select * from TestObj" ), [] )
```

Comment: When I do this I get an error: js: uncaught JavaScript runtime exception: TypeError: org.mozilla.javascript.Undefined@58d48756 is not a function, it is undefined.

Comment: For some reason it will run if I specify: db.query( new OSQLSynchQuery( "select * from TestObj" ), [] )